# HTTP POST to API Gateway endpoint from HTML Website Hyperlinks or Pictures

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, aws-api-gateway

I am setting up a simple self-service static website where you could click on certain elements (either a picture, or a hyperlink underneath) and it would fire off an HTTP POST using jQuery to an AWS API Gateway Endpoint that calls some other backend services (Lambda, Service APIs, etc).

It doesn't need to have anything special, just a simple POST with an empty body and the workflow will go along calling out the services, they are not expecting or needing input.

That said, I am not having any luck, I tried to include a `href` to the actual URL of the API Gateway API and that returns `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` which is a known behavior, testing with Postman and the API Gateway test suite returned 200 and behaved as expected, so it is not an issue with Authorization or other setup.

I have also tried a variation of the below

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("https://blahblah.execute-api.regionhere.amazonaws.com/test",
  {},
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

And it too returned `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` so I supposed it is not doing a HTTP POST at all and is behaving similar to clicking the hyperlink. Is there a better way to do with, especially with the requirement in mind that clicking a picture or another element in HTML would invoke this POST?

Comment: I suspect the problem you’re seeing is caused by the browser doing a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before even trying the POST request from your code, and the preflight is failing because the server is expecting authentication for OPTIONS requests. But your browser isn’t sending any authentication credentials in the OPTIONS request (and never will no matter if you add authentication credentials to the POST request). And I think the reason the browser is doing a preflight is that your jQuery call adds and X-Requested-With request header to the request, and jQuery has no option to suppress that

Comment: So your OPTIONS are (1) Configure the server to not require authentication for OPTIONS requests, but instead to respond with a 200 OK to OPTIONS, with the appropriate CORS headers, or (2) don’t use jQuery .post() but instead use the fetch API, like this: fetch(“ https://blahblah.execute-api.regionhere.amazonaws.com/test”, , {method: "POST"}).then(response => response.text).then(data => console.log(data))`. The fetch API doesn’t add the X-Requested-With header to requests (nor any additional headers), so that fetch call won’t trigger the browser do to a preflight.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have dropped all authorization requirements (since this will be hosted on S3 with a properly conditioned Bucket Policy for a Cognito App [which is its own nightmare]) I figure I can do away with it for now. I am still getting that issue anyway, and I do not know enough about jQuery to definitively say OPTIONS is causing me pain. My traces from the Gateway are basic caller IP and a 404. I am looking into `fetch` here now https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#post_request

Comment: @sideshowbarker I will play around with Fetch, now the question is how do I link up any of the elements in my HTML DIVs (pictures, hyperlinks, etc) to effectively call that `fetch()` operation upon clicking? Looks like the syntax is simple enough to implement an empty body and proper content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with HTML  formmethod Attribute, as described here (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formmethod.asp)

```html
---html stuff---
<form action="https://blah.execute-api.awsregion.amazonaws.com/test" method="post" target="_blank">
  <button class="deploy_button" type="submit" formmethod="post">Click to Deploy</button>
</form>
---more html stuff---
```

Didn't have to mess with CORS, the response body opens up in another Tab which is a nice prompt for the end-user to not continue to smash it, and also avoids me having to do some `onClick()` work for a pop-up box.